# Find the domain of convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(nx)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the domain of convergence of series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(nx)^n$$

I tried to find it by using the Root Test as follows:

$$=(nx)^{n/n}=nx$$
I know for convergency, the $(nx)$ should be less than one,but I couldnt how to complete the answer. Any help

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You can edit your comments within 5 minutes of posting. For bad MathJax I suggest typing it in the answer box for a preview first.

Comment: Thanks  @AlexR , but actually there's no need for hints anymore. Moreover, I don't *really* know why it came out twice. Maybe bad internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You want
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} |nx| \le 1$$
But this is only the case if $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a power series with coefficients $$a_n =n^n $$

The Cauchy-Hadamard formula gives

$$R^{-1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^n)^{1/n}=\infty $$

so that $R=0$.